# Short connecting flight in Doha. 55 minutes

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, short-connections, qatar-airways, doh

I have a short connection between flights from LHR to BKK via Doha. Fifty-five minutes. What would happen if my first leg flight is delayed and I miss the connection? I'm worried that I would have to pay for the extra leg to BKK. What rights do I have?
My ticket is a standard economy class ticket, non refundable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first flight is delayed and this causes you to misconnect, Qatar Airways will re-accommodate you free of charge on an alternative flight to Bangkok.

Comment: ... assuming that the two legs of the journey are booked on a single ticket.

Comment: ...which they should be because there are no other transit flights through Doha other than Qatar Airways.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think it is a safe bet that no one is buying separate tickets via Doha. The cost would be five-ten times higher than the through ticket.